# How to get the datetime of NYSE close time (4.00 PM EST) in UTC

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a background task that I want to schedule to run once the NYSE is closed.
My background scheduler (redis-rq) requires the time will be in UTC and I'm using python.
The task is scheduled during the trading day, so it means that I can't use offset or specific dates because it can be called dynamically.

So, what I just want is that once a trigger is called, I want to schedule the task to run at the end of the current trading day, which again is 16:00 EST time.

I've tried several options like getting the time in EST with:

```
datetime.time(16, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

But I can't figure out how to convert it to UTC, I tried stuff like .replace() with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*The task is scheduled during the trading day*" - sounds like you *do* have a date, i.e. the current date?

Comment: Yes, I want to run the task in the current day but in a fixed time in the future (16:00 EST)

Comment: According to a [NYSE web page](https://www.nyse.com/markets/hours-calendars) the usual 9:30 AM to 4:00 PM trading hours are ET, that is eastern time, which means EST in the winter and EDT in the summer. Also, on certain days near holidays trading closes at 1:00 PM ET.

Comment: @GerardAshton 'US/Eastern' might be an outdated time zone identifier, but IANA tz db links it to 'America/New_York', so DST/non-DST is accounted for. Your other remark about "certain" other closing times seem more complicated to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use today's date, combine with the desired NY time, set the time zone to New York (US Eastern), then convert to UTC:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, time
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9

t_utc = (
    datetime.combine(
        date.today(),
        time(16,0),
    )
    .replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
    .astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC"))
)

print(t_utc)
2023-05-10 20:00:00+00:00
```

Note on time zone handling:

- with the [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) `pytz` you cannot replace the tzinfo, use e.g. `pytz.timezone("America/New_York").localize(...` instead
- for zoneinfo to work properly on Windows, make sure to have `tzdata` package installed and up-to-date

Comment: Can it be done without the ZoneInfo package? like with using datetime.timezone only?

Comment: @Shayka no. You need a library to access time zone rules. That's what zoneinfo does now and pytz did in the past (you can still use it though).

Comment: So if I understand you right, can't I just use the UTC of the end trading hour (21:00 UTC) ? If UTC time is not changed on DST

Comment: @Shayka UTC does not change, but NY time does. 4 pm NY can e.g. mean 8 pm UTC or 9 pm UTC, depending on if daylight saving time is active or not. See Gerard Ashton's comment under your question.

Comment: Hi again, I'm struggling to update ZoneInfo on my machine, the following code won't be good?:
t_utc = (
    datetime.combine(
        date.today(),
        time(16,0),
    )
    .replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
    .astimezone(pytz.UTC)
)

Comment: @Shayka What do you mean by 'update ZoneInfo'? It's part of the standard library of Python 3.9 and higher. There's also a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/). If you insist on using pytz, you must localize. See my notes in the answer above. Your code will give invalid result if you use `replace` like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pytz library: https://pypi.org/project/pytz/ .

The code with this library can solve your task:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, time

nyse_close_time_et = time(16, 0)
now_et = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
nyse_close_datetime_et = datetime.combine(now_et.date(), nyse_close_time_et)
nyse_close_datetime_utc = nyse_close_datetime_et.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(nyse_close_datetime_utc)
```

Comment: You're not setting tzinfo to nyse_close_datetime_et, result will be wrong. Unless you *happen to be* in NY ;-) In general, [pytz is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/).

Answer (score -1):

US exchanges such as the NYSE or NASDAQ :

- pre-market hours  : 09.00 to 14:30 UTC
- trading hours     : 14.30 to 21:00 UTC
- after hours       : 21.00 to 01:00 UTC